# How to use a value inside a RecyclerView's TextView to set new value to the TextView from a Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am not sure how clear the title is but basically the application has a RecyclerView which is populated from a Room Database. I have two Room Databases, one for holding info on Markers and one for holding reference numbers to marker IDs of the other database and some other info.

Now the RecyclerView is populated with info from the database that holds the references to the marker IDs. I would like to get the referenced ID from the TextView and set the Text to the corresponding Marker's info from the database containing Markers.

First the Adapter, where I have bound the views and set the value for each view. Using the setJourneyObjectList() method to pass the information from the Fragment which holds the RecyclerView to the RecyclerView.

```
public class JourneyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JourneyAdapter.JourneyViewHolder> {
    private List<JourneyObject> journeyObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
...

  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JourneyAdapter.JourneyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        JourneyObject journeyObject = journeyObjectList.get(position);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(journeyObject.getTitle());
        holder.descriptionTextView.setText(journeyObject.getDescription());
        holder.countyTextView.setText(journeyObject.getCounty());
        holder.location1.setText(Integer.toString(journeyObject.getLocation1()));
        holder.location2.setText(Integer.toString(journeyObject.getLocation2()));
    
   public void setJourneyObjectList(List<JourneyObject> journeyObjectList){
        this.journeyObjectList = journeyObjectList;
        notifyDataSetChanged()

 class JourneyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     
        TextView location1, location2, location3, location4, location5;
        public JourneyViewHolder(final View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.journeyTitleText);
            countyTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.journeyCountyText);
            descriptionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.journeyDescriptionText);
            location1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.journeyloc1);
            location2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.journeyloc2);
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is the Fragment with the RecyclerView from which I set the RecyclerView Adapter and set the List from which to populate the RecyclerView.

Now at the end of this Fragment I found the View which is inside the RecyclerView Item and tried to set the Text to the title of the Marker with the received ID. I know it will not work like this but this is just for clarity of what I am trying to do.

```
public class TabJourneyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MarkerViewModel markerViewModel;
    private JourneyViewModel journeyViewModel;

    public TabJourneyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_journey, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.journeyRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        JourneyAdapter journeyAdapter = new JourneyAdapter(requireActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(journeyAdapter);

        markerViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MarkerViewModel.class);
        journeyViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(JourneyViewModel.class);

        journeyViewModel.getAllJourneyInfo().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<JourneyObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<JourneyObject> journeyObjects) {
                journeyAdapter.setJourneyObjectList(journeyObjects);
            }
        });
        TextView location1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.journeyloc1);

        markerViewModel.getAllMarkers().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<MarkerObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MarkerObject> markerObjects) {
                for (MarkerObject markerObject : markerObjects){
                    if (location1 != null){
                        if (location1.getText().equals(Integer.toString(markerObject.getId()))){
                            location1.setText(markerObject.getTitle());
                        }
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help and that I was clear enough to be understood.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change title based on marker id ,send both markerObject,journeyObjects into your adapter.

```
 journeyViewModel.getAllJourneyInfo().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<JourneyObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<JourneyObject> journeyObjects) {
            //add this journyObjects in List
          journeyObjectsList.addAll(journeyObjects);
        }
    });
   

    markerViewModel.getAllMarkers().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<MarkerObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<MarkerObject> markerObjects) {
           //set adapter here for recyclerView

            markerObjectsList.addAll(markerObjects);

            //change adapter constructor based on this argument
           journeyAdapter.setJourneyObjectList(journeyObjectsList,markerObjectList);
        }
    });
```

//then set Title for each text view in onBindViewHolder()

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JourneyAdapter.JourneyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    JourneyObject journeyObject = journeyObjectList.get(position);
    
    holder.location1.setText(Integer.toString(journeyObject.getLocation1()));
    
     
     for (int i=0;i<markerObjectList.size();i++){
                
                    if (location1 != null && location1.getText().equals(Integer.toString(markerObjectList.get(i).getId()))){
                        location1.setText(markerObjectList.get(i).getTitle());
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```